# How to think of a 'begin' block in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia v1.6.3 in [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)). According to Julia's documentation, a *begin* block does not introduce a new scope. Now, consider these two blocks of code:

```
x = 1
begin
   local x = 0
   for i = 1:10
      x += 10
   end
end
println(x)
```

These lines would print out 1. I'm guessing what happened is a local x is created within the *begin* block, and the *for* loop would use and modify that local x. As a result, the x in the main scope is not changed.

The second block of code is as follows:

```
x = 1
local x = 0
for i = 1:10
    x += 10
end
println(x)
```

These lines would print out 101. I'm guessing the "local x = 0" statement didn't change anything in the main scope, and in the *for* loop we are using the global variable x assigned at the beginning.

So surely the *begin* block does something here, but I'm not exactly sure how to think of it if we don't think of it as some sort of "new scope".

Comment: I think it is a bug.

Comment: Most likely your question will be resolved by documentation clarification. See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/42664. I will add an answer here when the documentation is cleaned up.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the comment! I'll follow up with the GitHub page.

Comment: Yeah it's one of those unintuitive stuff like soft scope (unrelated) that I'd rather be changed in v2. The one use of this I've heard of is getting around the need of a macro to switch to using the `global` keyword when evaluated in a global scope it can't even detect it's being evaluated in, but I'd rather there be an alternative like using the `outer` keyword (https://discourse.julialang.org/t/should-macros-get-an-istoplevel-or-scope-argument/44850)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "begin block does not introduce new scope," by itself, without the `local` keyword. However a `local` keyword declaration of a variable is nevertheless local to the scope of an enclosing begin/end block.